# Graph theory: Closed neighourhoods and generalized clustering coefficients

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, tiling, definitions

The [neighbourhood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbourhood_(graph_theory)) of node $v$ in graph $G$ is the subgraph of $G$ induced by all vertices adjacent to $v$.

[image] [image]  [image]

The number of edges between neighbours divided by the number of pairs of neighbours is the so-called [clustering coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clustering_coefficient) $c$. The first node has $c = 6 / \binom{6}{2} = 0.4$, the second $c = 2 / \binom{5}{2} = 0.2$, the third $c = 0$

You now may add nodes at larger distances from node $v$ to its neighbourhood when they lie on minimal cycles going through $v$:

[image][image]

My first question is: **What's the official name of such "closed neighbourhoods"?** For [tilings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tessellation) the closed neighbourhood of a vertex is essentially its [**vertex configuration**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_configuration), but what about the general case? Would one call the closed neighbourhood "vertex configuration", too?

In any case, the concept of clustering coefficients now can be generalized. Let me first note that the name "clustering coefficient" is not the best that could have been chosen. It is true that triangles are  [complete graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_graph) $K_3$ and thus are *clusters*, but they are also *cycles*, i.e. [cycle graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_graph) $C_3$, and so "cycle coefficient" would have been an equivalent name – or to be specific: "3-cycle coefficient".

The concept of clustering coefficients – considered as cycle coefficients – can be generalized quite naturally: The $k$-cycle coefficient $c_k$ of a node $v$ is the number of induced minimal $k$-cycles $C_k$ it lies on, divided by the number of *possible* such $k$-cycles. The overall cycle coefficient $\mathbf{c}$ can then be defined as the sum $\mathbf{c} = \sum_{k=3}^n c_k$ and cannot exceed 1 which is achieved exactly for the nodes of the complete graph $K_n$, for which $c_k = \delta_{k3}$. For the cycle graph $C_n$ the cycle coefficient of all nodes is $\mathbf{c} = 1 / n!$. For trees we have of course $\mathbf{c} = 0$.

Reference request: **Under which name (and where) are such "cycle coefficients" investigated in the literature?**

Comment: I think one obstacle here is the definition of a `minimal cycle'. It's obvious how to choose these in sufficiently nice embeddings of a sufficiently connected graph into a surface (as you have done with the tiling examples), but for more general graphs we need a different notion of what cycles to count.

Comment: @BrandonduPreez: What would be wrong with this definition: *A cycle is minimal iff the subgraph induced by it is a cycle, too*? In other words: *A cycle is minimal iff it is isomorphic to the subgraph induced by it.*

Comment: @BrandonduPreez: Since you seem to be interested in distances in graphs you might want to have a look at this question [The distance distribution of graphs](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/371339/the-distance-distribution-of-graphs). And maybe also at this interactive visualization tool, especially for distances in graphs: [SRGX](http://syspedia.de/ComplexEpidemics/index.html?lang=en)

Comment: That definition is fine, but it is worth noting that even for 2-connected graphs in the plane, the cycles you end up with are not the same as those considered by the vertex configuration (you can have chords that lie `outside' the faces incident with a vertex).

Comment: Thanks for the recommend, I'll give it a look.

Comment: @BrandonduPreez: That's perfectly true, and that's why I wrote that for tilings the closed neighbourhood of a vertex is **essentially** its vertex configuration,

Comment: Hmm, for the sake of simplicity, it may be worth considering the following (I will confess I am slightly out of my depth here, so just spitballing): Every cycle $C_k$ passing through a vertex $v$ is contained in the ball $B(v, \lfloor \frac{k}{2} \rfloor)$. Thus it *may* be easier to let your $k$-cycle neighborhoods just be the balls $B(v, \lfloor \frac{k}{2} \rfloor)$. For sufficiently dense graphs, this won't add many vertices (the ball approximates the closed neighborhood well), and your problem reduces to counting cycles through a central vertex in a graph of radius $k$.